# Getting "InvalidPart: null" when uploading multipart form

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, multipart

I am trying to upload big file to S3 in node JavaScript.
All the parts uploded but, in the MultipartUpload, when I try to unite all parts there is error:

> InvalidPart: null

This is the relevant code:

```
let partNumber=1;
let numPartsUploaded=0;

readStream.on("data", (chunk)=>{
  
  s3.uploadPart(partParams, (err,data)=>{
  if(err){
    console.log("Error upload part", err)
    return;}
  consol.log(`part ${partNumber} uploaded successfully`)
  parts.push({ETag:data.ETag,PartNumber:partNumber});
  partNumber++;
  numPartsUploaded++;
  if(numPartsUploaded===Math.ceil(readStream.bytesRead/partSize)){
    s3.completeMultipartUpload({
      Bucket="myBucketName",
      Key="name",
      UploadId:uploadId,
      MultipartUpload:{Parts:parts},},(err,data)=>{
        if(err){
          consol.log("error: ",err) 
          return;}
        consol.log("file uploaded successfully")
      });}});});
```

I also don't see the parts in the S3, but maybe I can't see it until the upload is finish?

I loged the parts array and it looks good without null.

Comment: Please try to be more specific by providing minimum and to the point code.